# File copied by `make dist` but not by `make distcheck`

Tags: autotools

In a project built with GNU Autotools, I have a script that needs to modified by `make` to contain the installation path. Here's a small example:

**configure.ac:**

```
AC_INIT(foobar, 1.0)
AC_PREREQ(2.66)
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS(config.h)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(foreign)
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile blah/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**Makefile.am:**

```
SUBDIRS = blah
```

**blah/Makefile.am:**

```
all: myscript

myscript: myscript.in
        sed -e 's,@datadir\@,$(pkgdatadir),g' myscript.in > myscript
        chmod +x myscript

EXTRA_DIST = myscript.in
```

`./configure; make` successfully creates `myscript`. Ditto for `make dist; tar xvzf foobar-1.0.tar.gz; cd foobar-1.0; ./configure; make`. However, `make distcheck` fails because the file `myscript.in` is missing (but it is copied successfully with `make dist`).

Any ideas why the file `myscript.in` is not being copied by `make distcheck`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

myscript.in is in the distribution tarball, but make distcheck does a VPATH build in which configure is run from a different directory.  eg, instead of "./configure", it is doing something akin to "mkdir build-dir; cd build-dir; /path/to/configure;"  In Makefile.am, you need to replace instances of "myscript.in" in the myscript rule and dependency line with "$(srcdir)/myscript.in"